# How to Stop for Button Handler - Android

Tags: android, button, handler

When I call a buttonHandler, the app just continues in the background even though the Handler didn't finish, how can I stop this behaviour, and fall back to a linear execution?

```
qrscan.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() { //the Button listener
    public void onClick(View view) { //the handler
      if(initiateScan(activity) == null) //first thing i expect it to execute
         initiateSend(activity); //the next thing which should be executed AFTER
      }
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't saying much - we'll need to know how `initiateScan` and `initiateSend` work, but it sounds like `initiateScan` is using [`startActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) or [`startActivityForResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) to do it's thing.

If so, you need to ensure they are using [`startActivityForResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29), and move `initiateSend` to the [`onActivityResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) method of your activity.

Activities are asynchronous entities and you need to make use of the [`onActivityResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) callback to handle actions in the linear manner you are looking for.

For more info, read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities).